# how to find the xpath which is beside the element i already know?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-crawler

i am working on a crawler based on selenium.I expect to crwal "https://sukebei.nyaa.si/?s=seeders&o=desc"(which is a porn torrent web) and only download every torrent on that day.Thus,i have to use "driver.find_element_by_link_text("date")" to detect whether the date is correct and save those elements as a list.After that,i have no idea what to do so as to click the hyperlink next to the date.
If you have any idea please let me know,thank you.(By a Taiwanese high school student with poor English.)
[part of html of that web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlD2N.jpg)
[image of that web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQAQs.jpg)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
date="2021-"
month=input("what month is it?")
day=input("which day is it?")
print(date+month+"-"+day)
url="https://sukebei.nyaa.si/?s=seeders&o=desc"

driver_path = "C:\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe"
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=option)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)

j=1
for j in driver.find_element_by_link_text("date"):
    

time.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to form the correct date (with the form that appears in the web), and then, find the elements by link text or by the attribute where appears the date, but THE ELEMENTS, not the element:

```
driver.find_elements_by_link_text("format_date")
```

Then, you have the elements you want; you only need to pick up the part of then that you want, you need a for or something to locate any element of the selection, and you need to do something like:

```
singleElement.get_attribute("href")
```

You can put inside ("") the attribute you want to save.